# How to link my content to a Google+ profile using "rel=author"?

Tags: google, google-plus, rel

I googled this question and found the answer from [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2539557) but in featured Google+ I didn't find the options that are mentioned in the above URL. I need my Google+ profile should be resulted in Google result for my keyword. How I can connect my Google+ profile and my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to edit your profile (click on "Profile" in the sidebar) so it includes the website in question in your "Contributor to" section.

Then, you need to place a link on any page that you want the Google+ Authorship system to take effect that links to your Google+ profile.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/[Profile ID]" rel="author">My Google+ Profile</a>
```

Comment: @JohnSanjay No problem :)